# Give param before filename with .htaccess and serve to php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have very poor knowledge about .htaccess

**Goal:**
Param **can** be set before index like: www.example.com/**param**/index
 . Param also can not be set (www.example.com/index).

In php i need get this param something like `$_GET['param']`

Orginal file structure are: www.example.com/index.php

Note. Index.php can by any file

Now i have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

How to remove `.php` extension at filename end. How to continue this?

www.example.com can by any http, https, non-www, www domain

Comment: @anubhava Yes. param is required for any other .php file..

Comment: What should be value of `$_GET['param']` when URL is `www.example.com/index` and what should be value of `$_GET['param']` when URL is `www.example.com/param/index`?

Comment: @anubhava it`s not important. It`s for language codes: eng, ru, de... etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I interpret the question correctly, you can use these rules in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?param=en [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $2.php?param=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL /ru/index was not found on this server.

Comment: With these exact rules `http://localhost/ru/index` works for me and rewrites to `http://localhost/index.php?ru=ru`. Make sure this is kept in **root** .htaccess and there is no other rule in this htaccess

Comment: default param works, but another variable dont parse